# Dockerfile - Can't use another name than 'app.py'

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, dockerfile

I've been searching a lot for the past days reagarding Dockerfile. I'm using cx_Oracle in python 2.7. Here's how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM sbanal/python-oracle-xe12.1-latest

WORKDIR /code/app
COPY generate_distance.py /code/app/app.py
COPY generate_values.py /code/app/app2.py
```

To make it easier to explain, I've made a method to print out the name of the file. In generate_distance.py:

```
def test():
    print "Generate distance"

test()
```

In generate_values.py:

```
def test():
    print "Generate values"

test()
```

Then I'm running docker build with a tag:

```
docker build -t gen .      
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.82kB
Step 1/4 : FROM sbanal/python-oracle-xe12.1-latest
 ---> 723335924016
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /code/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9fde6fb3ac02
Step 3/4 : COPY generate_distance.py /code/app/app.py
 ---> 1dbf7ef85ee3
Removing intermediate container ae626dcef48c
Step 4/4 : COPY generate_values.py /code/app/app2.py
 ---> 7a54500b88a3
Removing intermediate container f496edfc237d
Successfully built 7a54500b88a3
Successfully tagged gen:latest
```

When running 'docker images', I can see the 'gen' image. But when I run the 'gen' image, only app.py is working:

```
>docker run -p 5500:5000 gen
>Generate distance
```

I can't see what mistake I've done. I also don't know why it has to be called app.py. If I use different file name during COPY in Dockerfile, I get 'No such file or directory' error. That is:

```
FROM sbanal/python-oracle-xe12.1-latest

WORKDIR /code/app
COPY generate_relation_distance.py /code/app/generate_relation_distance.py
COPY generate_ten_values.py /code/app/generate_ten_values.py
```

Build and run like the part over:

```
docker run -p 5500:5000 gen
python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is based on [sbanal/python-oracle-xe12.1-latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/sbanal/python-oracle-xe12.1-latest/~/dockerfile/) (first line of your Dockerfile).

In this Dockerfile is a "CMD" defined, which specifies the first command of your container. Here, that is

```
CMD python app.py
```

(see [last line of your base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sbanal/python-oracle-xe12.1-latest/~/dockerfile/)).

The command will be executed as `sh -c "python app.py"`.

This is why your Dockerfile starts on container creation `python app.py`

You need to override the "CMD" part in your Dockerfile, e.g.

```
CMD ["python", "app2.py"]
```

See the [official docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) to understand CMD.

You should only have one CMD in your Dockerfile containing the first command, which is automatically executed by the container.

If you want to start multiple services, you should consider, if this should really be packed into one image. Or you follow the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/) and consider using a supervisor or a script, which starts your desired services.

Comment: Cool, thanks for fast answer. Do you know how I can run both of them? :)

Comment: I implemented this in one project with a [supervisor](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) which appeared to be one of the cleanest solutions.

Comment: Or since you now know how the first CMD command is translated to shell syntax, you can use this to start multiple processes. Depends on how you want it to be running

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me some code hint? 

Comment: There are [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/) for this purpose with code examples.

I chose the supervisord in this project, while [this](https://github.com/Phaetec/pogo-cruncher/blob/master/supervisord.conf) is the config file and [that](https://github.com/Phaetec/pogo-cruncher/blob/master/Dockerfile) is the Dockerfile for it.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for your time. Really appreciate your answer 

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wondering how I solved the problem, I used bash script instead.

script.sh:

```
#Build the image
docker build -t image_name .

#Run image image_name in container
docker run -d -p 550:500 image_name tail -f /dev/null

#Get the container id
container_id="$(docker ps | grep $IMAGE_NAME | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+')"

#Run your program in container
docker exec -it container_id /bin/sh -c "python generate_distance.py"
docker exec -it container_id /bin/sh -c "python generate_values.py"
```

My goal was to store the output in text files and copy those from docker container to localhost.